# minOccurs maxOccurs don't work with dita?

Tags: dita

I had modify the minOccurs = 1 with a element in xsd, and didn't add the element in ditamap. But the dita work well. No warning, No error.
The example is the bookmap which is form samples of dita-ot-3.3.

xsd:

```
   <xs:group name="bookmeta.content">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="linktext" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="searchtitle" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="shortdesc" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="author" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="source" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="publisherinformation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="critdates" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="permissions" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="metadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="audience" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="category" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="keywords" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="prodinfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="othermeta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="resourceid" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="ux-window" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="bookid" minOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:group ref="bookchangehistory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="bookrights" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:group ref="data" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:group>
```

ditamap:

```
  <bookmeta>
    <author>Howe Tuduit</author>
    <bookid>
      <isbn>071271271X</isbn>
      <booknumber>SG99-9999-00</booknumber>
      <maintainer>
        <organization>Retro Tools</organization>
        <person/>
      </maintainer>
    </bookid>
    <bookrights>
      <copyrfirst>
        <year>2004</year>
      </copyrfirst>
      <copyrlast>
        <year>2007</year>
      </copyrlast>
      <bookowner>
        <organization>Retro Tools, Inc.</organization>
      </bookowner>
    </bookrights>
  </bookmeta>
```

I think the minOccurs should be work. Output will be fail.

Comment: What .xsd file did you edit??

Comment: I just modify the minOccurs from "0" to "1".

Comment: I found that the constraint is fine when using editor (PTC Arbortext Editor), but the dita compile is don't work, still output. no error, no warning.

Comment: Does editor and DITA-OT reference the same XSD file you modified?

Answer (score 0):

You must have modified another XSD file that is different from DITA-OT references.

If I modify `dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.oasis-open.dita.v1_3\schema\bookmap\xsd\bookmapMod.xsd` for testing, DITA-OT build fails with following error. This is expected result.

[bookmapMod.xsd]

```
  <xs:group name="bookmeta.content">
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="linktext" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="searchtitle" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="shortdesc" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="author" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="source" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="publisherinformation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="critdates" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="permissions" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="metadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="audience" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="category" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="keywords" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="prodinfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="othermeta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="resourceid" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="ux-window" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="bookid" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="bookchangehistory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="bookrights" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:group ref="data" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
```

[Bookmap]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:dita:xsd:bookmap.xsd">
    <booktitle>
        <mainbooktitle>BookMapTest</mainbooktitle>
    </booktitle>
    <bookmeta>
        <author>Howe Tuduit</author>
        <bookid>
            <isbn>071271271X</isbn>
            <booknumber>SG99-9999-00</booknumber>
            <maintainer>
                <organization>Retro Tools</organization>
                <person/>
            </maintainer>
        </bookid>
        <bookrights>
            <copyrfirst>
                <year>2004</year>
            </copyrfirst>
            <copyrlast>
                <year>2007</year>
            </copyrlast>
            <bookowner>
                <organization>Retro Tools, Inc.</organization>
            </bookowner>
        </bookrights>
    </bookmeta>
    <chapter navtitle="Chapter"/>
</bookmap>
```

[Error Log]

> BUILD FAILED
>   D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.dita.base\build.xml:31: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.dita.base\build_preprocess.xml:62:
>   Failed to run pipeline: [DOTJ012F][FATAL] Failed to parse the input
>   file
>   'file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/dita/20190402-xsd/Bookmaptest.ditamap'.:
>   file:/C:/Users/toshi/OneDrive/Documents/test/dita/20190402-xsd/Bookmaptest.ditamap
>   Line -1:Invalid content was found starting with element 'author'. One
>   of '{linktext}' is expected.
>
> Total time: 2 seconds

Please note that modifying directly OASIS XSD file is not recommended way. This is only done for testing.

[The answer to HTML Help output]

> I modify
>   dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.oasis-open.dita.v1_3\schema\bookmap\xsd\bookmapMod.xsd like yours then compile with: dita -f htmlhelp -i
>   D:\dita-ot-3.3\docsrc\samples\taskbook.ditamap -o F:\Study\Dita\output
>   -v. Of course, I modify the taskbook references with bookmap.xsd not DTD. The output still fine. No error. –

This is because HTML Help output adopts "preprocess2" introduced below:

[Map-first preprocessing](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/reference/map-first-preprocessing.html)

If you modify following line from "preprocess2" to "preprocess" in dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.dita.htmlhelp\build_dita2htmlhelp.xml, you will surely get the validation error.

```
<target name="dita2htmlhelp" unless="noMap" depends="dita2htmlhelp.init,
build-init, use-init.envhhcdir, use-init.hhcdir, preprocess2,
htmlhelp.topics, htmlhelp.copy-image, copy-css">
<antcall target="dita.map.htmlhelp"/>
</target>
```

> preprocess.init:
>
> ```
>  [echo] *****************************************************************
>
>  [echo] * input = D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-3.3\docsrc\samples\taskbook.ditamap
>
>  [echo] *****************************************************************
> ```
>
> ditaval-merge:
>
> gen-list:  [gen-list] Using Xerces grammar pool for DTD and schema
>   caching.  [gen-list] Processing
>   file:/D:/DITA-OT/dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/taskbook.ditamap Error:
>   Failed to run pipeline: [DOTJ012F][FATAL] Failed to parse the input
>   file 'file:/D:/DITA-OT/dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/taskbook.ditamap'.:
>   file:/D:/DITA-OT/dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/taskbook.ditamap Line
>   14:cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'author'. One of '{linktext}' is expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still confuse because I can't find the different between your modify and mine. I modify dita-ot-3.3\plugins\org.oasis-open.dita.v1_3\schema\bookmap\xsd\bookmapMod.xsd like yours then compile with: dita -f htmlhelp -i D:\dita-ot-3.3\docsrc\samples\taskbook.ditamap -o F:\Study\Dita\output -v. Of course, I modify the taskbook references with bookmap.xsd not DTD. The output still fine. No error.

Comment: @Stone I added the answer for your question.

Comment: I got the error info and will learn more about dita. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stone I will also ask the reason to the Google DITA-OT user's forum,

Comment: @Stone logged here [https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/3281](https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/3281)